# Search with multiple inputs with third table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 tables and tables have some relationships between each other.

**Table 1:** Reports `{id, date, employee_id}`

```
public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, "employee_id", "id");
}
```

**Table 2:** Employees `{id, name, department_id}`

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}

public function report()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Report::class, "employee_id", "id");
}
```

Table 3: Departments `{id, name}`

```
public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
    }
```

That is the issue, I want to make search in Reports table with multiple inputs like below

2 date field to filter between date: `start TO end`

1 input for `employee id`

1 input `department_id`

and it's goes on with other inputs but no need to list them all because there is only one relationship between them with Reports table. For example `report_status_id` has relationship with `ReportStatus` etc.

Here is my search controller:

```
$reports = DB::table('reports')
            ->leftJoin('employees', 'employees.id', '=', 'reports.employee_id')
            ->leftJoin('departments', 'departments.id', '=', 'employees.department_id')
            ->whereBetween('date', [$request->start_date, $request->end_date])
            ->where([
                ['employee_id', $request->employee_id],
                ['report_status_id', $request->report_status_id],
            ])
            ->orWhere('department_id', $request->department_id)
            ->get();
```

I'm not controlling user for which input has been filled. But this is the problem: If user ONLY fill the `department` input for search, as you can guess I have to list all reports with that department but since there is no any information about employee, the results become inconsistent.

For example if user selects **ONLY** `Incoming` department, it returns `1484` results. But if user choose `Incoming` department with dates between `2022-01-01 TO 2022-02-01` it returns `1512` result which is impossible. It should narrow down as you can imagine.

I know my search logic is not true and just added to show something but I think you understand my problem. How can I organize the logic and get consistent results? I'm open to any kind of solution.

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Since `$request->department_id` can return `int` or `null` you can refactor your query using eloquent builder like this:

```
$query = Report::query();

if($request->start_date && $request->end_date){
  $query->whereBetween('date', [$request->start_date, $request->end_date]);
} else if ($request->start_date && $request->end_date === null){
  $query->where('date', '>=', $request->start_date)
} else if ($request->start_date === null && $request->end_date){
  $query->where('date', '=<', $request->end_date)
}

if($request->employee_id){
  $query->where('employee_id', '=', $request->employee_id);
}

if($request->request_status_id){
  $query->where('request_status_id', '=', $request->request_status_id);
}

if($request->department_id){
  $departmentId = $request->department_id;
  $query->with('employee')
    ->orWhereHas('employee', function (Builder $q) use ($departmentId): void {
       $q->where('department_id', '=', $departmentId)     
});
}

$result = $query->get(); //$result now has collection
```

Comment: Awesome approach, but instead of nested if loops, it should be more consistent. For example I need to add date conditions to department loop to and it goes on. 

What if employees and department selected in the same time etc...

I have too many field in search form. In fact I'm trying to make this search form because I have too many rows and columns and packs like Livewire Powertables are too slow and gives wrong filtering results sometimes in some conditions.

Comment: I gave that to you to see how you can improve your query and the way how you approach the problem. In fact we have to consider what fields are required and what not, an some other conditions. Also the question why it query inconsistent results, you have to debug this. Or install `telescope` or `var_dump` prepared query and check for consistency with your desired query.

Comment: First of all thank you for answer. I'm dealing with over 100.000 rows with over 30 columns and extensions are not optimized well I guess. First of all Livewire Powergrid is too slow, not usable. For example when I'm filtering the date between 2022-01-01 and 2022-02-01, it also return 2021-12-31 too. This is only one example. I can't review all columns to be sure if its true or not. Or maybe I can make some modification on search form. For example, it doesn't make any sense to choose both employee and department. Department must override selection of employee. Those kind of modifications.

Comment: @VitoAndolini "For example, it doesn't make any sense to choose both employee and department. Department must override selection of employee. Those kind of modifications." it is all depends on your logic, and that can be achieved.